# Magento Add Fee or Discount to Order Totals

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, onepage-checkout, sales-order

I am using a module [provided in this link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)

it is working fine for all payment methods except the online transaction. For that I am using PayU money. The same module is used everywhere but it is not only working in online transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer.

The issue with the payment gateway third-party checkout and overriding the Magento's checkout. In the extension also the grandTotal is updating for all online transactions held so after the online payment done I have updated the grandTotal again in the extensions observer and it's done.

Now it's updating my grandTotal for every order placed.